# Gas stove sparks but won’t light. No gas smell either.

Tags: gas, stove

For some reason my gas stove will not light and I do not know why.

Some context: yesterday a flexy tube broke on the bidet. Water went everywhere so knobs were turned in a panic. A new tube was bought. Everything was fixed.

However the next day I realised the hot water had been turned off in chaos. I turned it back on. All good. But the gas stove no longer seems to work.

I should admit even after replacing the flexy tube the gas worked because we had pasta on the hob. So some time between the pasta being made and now the gas has stopped working.

I have cleaned the stove but all i hear when i turn the dial is the clicking sound. Since it worked last night but not now i feel the solution would be something simple.

Any ideas before I resort to calling a handyman?

here are pictures of all dials and handles in my apartment.

https://ibb.co/buJEZw
https://ibb.co/hYDRgb
https://ibb.co/bAVTuw
https://ibb.co/nFrZZw
https://ibb.co/bxORgb

Answer (score 3):

I started this as a comment, but it started getting long, so here goes.

**Without more detail and pictures, I would recommend calling in a local expert to look things over, just on the basis of not having you taking a half-baked, uninformed guess from an anonymous person on the Internet as a reliable answer.**

Having said that and meaning it...

Is there a control lockout feature on your stove? That would prevent it from supplying gas to the burners (leaking gas into your residence) after a power loss.

Is there a gas valve on the stove itself that got turned?

Otherwise, you probably just have the gas shutoff valve for the stove turned off. Typically (unless it's old), a gas valve will have a yellow handle or knob, or possibly a red or plain brass one. But it will tend to be a valve that rotates just 90 degrees rather than a round knob that you turn multiple times to open or close the valve. Although, it *could* be a rotary valve.

If it is a newer 90 degree valve and installed correctly, it will be open if the handle is aligned with the pipe, and closed if the handle is perpendicular to the pipe. Although, another caveat, there are also valves built on elbow fittings. I've attached a couple of example images below.

Offhand, it sounds like there just isn't any gas getting to the burners on your stove. Any link to the bidet is probably incidental, since you already know that you were turning both water and gas supply knobs around the house trying to make the water stop. I doubt that your bidet has its own gas supply, and the "flexy tube" is probably just water, right?

You should have a separate gas valve for each gas-fired appliance, somewhere close to the appliance. You have to be able to turn the gas off for just the stove so that it can be disconnected and removed (maintenance, replacement, etc.) without turning the gas off for all the other appliances in the residence. The gas shutoff valve for the stove should be somewhere near the stove so that if you disconnect it, you aren't evacuating all of the gas in the line between the stove and the main gas valve into the residence.

You could easily have the main gas supply valve open, have the gas valve for the water heater open, but have the gas valve for the stove closed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Craig, thank you for your response. All the levers in my house are aligned with the pipes. I forgot to attach this image, if it makes any difference. One of the levers is perpendicular, not aligned but I am unable to turn this. It's very stiff. I'm referring to the one below the top lever.  https://ibb.co/euY1hR

Comment: Craig, it turns out that last picture I sent with the perpendicular lever was the problem. I couldn't turn it back on because you actually have to PUSH the lever in to be able to turn it. A safety feature that went right over my head. Thanks for your help buddy!